# How to do what strava does when it goes to background while recording iOS

Tags: objective-c, timer, background, strava

I am trying to do what strava does when going into background. When I put strava in background while recording, the clock on my iPhone on the top left goes blue and whenever you click on it strava opens up. I was wondering what is that feature called and how you do it programmatically. Currently I am using objective-c so it will be more helpful to have that in the answer instead of swift.

Edit: I figured it out, it was locationManager setShowBackgroundLocationIndicator.